# push 1 script out of many to a unique repository

Tags: git

I have my main repository and inside my many scripts I have 1 script I want to go to another repository.

Is this possible ?

I know I can make a separate repo and directory, place the script in there and then push that way but I was thinking there must be to push 1 item in a repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I can make a separate repo and directory, place the script in there and then push that way but I was thinking there must be to push 1 item in a repo.

That's the only way. This is because a directory IS a repository when it has a `.git` subdirectory. There's no way to separate these two concepts. So whatever is in that directory that you committed cannot be separated out other than just make another repository/directory.